# Native base DatePicker inside a functional component throwing error

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-native, native-base

I am trying to use native base [Datepicker](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref) but I am getting this error. On clicking to date picked I want to display the date selector calendar and pick a date but I am getting an error.

Here is my code

```
const PublicMenu = () => {
const [date, setDate] = useState("");
return(
   <View
                  style={{
                    borderColor: "black",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    height: hp("3.5%"),
                    width: wp("40%"),
                  }}
                >
                  <DatePicker
                    defaultDate={new Date(2018, 4, 4)}
                    minimumDate={new Date(2018, 1, 1)}
                    maximumDate={new Date(2018, 12, 31)}
                    locale={"en"}
                    timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
                    modalTransparent={false}
                    animationType={"fade"}
                    androidMode={"default"}
                    placeHolderText='Select date'
                    textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
                    placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
                    onDateChange={(date) => setDate(date)}
                    disabled={false}
                  />
                </View>

)
};
```

On clicking the date picker I am getting this error, do anyone know how can I resolve it.

ERROR BELOW:

```
Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as `value`.

This error is located at:
    in Picker (at DatePicker.js:94)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at Modal.js:220)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Modal.js:242)
    in RCTModalHostView (at Modal.js:228)
    in Modal (at DatePicker.js:80)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:64)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:63)
    in DatePicker (at PubishMenu.js:116)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:108)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:100)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:93)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:84)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:83)
    in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:1124)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1260)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1286)
    in ScrollView (at PubishMenu.js:82)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at PubishMenu.js:42)
    in PublicMenu (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at HomeNavigation.js:34)
    in HomeNavigation (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at navigations/index.js:18)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at navigations/index.js:17)
    in AppNavigator (at Main.js:26)
    in Main (at App.js:13)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)     
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:12)
    in Provider (at App.js:11)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl      
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error  
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error   
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15257:32 in logCapturedError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15361:20 in logError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16597:12 in update.callback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7106:2 in callCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7127:20 in commitUpdateQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15801:25 in commitLifeCycles
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a problem with native-base DatePicker implementation, you can find a workaround here https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3381#issuecomment-791300821
or use react-native-datepicker directly

Comment: Native base documentation is also so bad. I used react-native-datepicker instead.