# Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as `value`. How to fix that with datepicker?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to add a datepicker to my form created using nativebase in React-Native.

But I am getting error as Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as `value`.

my code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Content,
  H1,
  Text,
  Form,
  Item,
  Input,
  DatePicker,
} from "native-base";

export default function createOrder() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [count, setCount] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [commission, setCommission] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  // used to regulate when calculations are made
  const [focusedInput, setFocus] = useState(null);
  console.log(date);

  // run an effect when price, count, or amount changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // if price and count exist and user isnt changing amount, calculate amount
    if (price && count && focusedInput !== "amount") {
      setAmount((parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(count)).toString());
    }
    // if price and count exist and user isnt changing count, calculate count
    else if (price && amount && focusedInput !== "count") {
      setCount((parseFloat(amount) / parseFloat(price)).toString());
    }
  }, [price, count, amount]);
  // when amount changes, update commission and total
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(amount))) setCommission("");
    if (amount) setCommission((parseFloat(amount) * 0.002).toString());
  }, [amount]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Form>
          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder="coin name"
              onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder="number of coins"
              onChangeText={(text) => setCount(text)}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              value={count}
              onFocus={() => setFocus("count")}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder="Amount Invested"
              onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(text)}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              value={amount}
              onFocus={() => setFocus("amount")}
            />
          </Item>

          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder="coin price"
              onChangeText={(text) => setPrice(text)}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              value={price}
              onFocus={() => setFocus("price")}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item last>
            <DatePicker
              style={{ width: 200 }}
              date={date}
              mode="date"
              placeholder="select date"
              format="YYYY-MM-DD"
              minDate="2016-05-01"
              maxDate="2017-11-01"
              confirmBtnText="Confirm"
              cancelBtnText="Cancel"
              onDateChange={(date) => setDate(date)}
            />
          </Item>
        </Form>
        <Text>Commission: {commission}</Text>
        <Text>
          Total Amount:{" "}
          {(parseFloat(commission) + parseFloat(amount)).toString()}
        </Text>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I checked with the default [sample](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref) provided in the native base examples also.But same error as below.

When I click on select date field in the UI, then I am getting this error.

[image: UI]

```
Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as `value`.

This error is located at:
    in RNDateTimePicker (at DatePicker.js:94)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at Modal.js:220)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Modal.js:242)
    in RCTModalHostView (at Modal.js:228)
    in Modal (at DatePicker.js:80)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:64)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at DatePicker.js:63)
    in DatePicker (at DatePickerExample.jsx:17)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:1124)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1260)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1286)
    in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:487)
    in KeyboardAwareScrollView (at Content.js:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SafeAreaView.js:41)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at Content.js:36)
    in Content (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Content) (at DatePickerExample.jsx:16)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Container.js:12)
    in Container (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Container) (at DatePickerExample.jsx:14)
    in DatePickerExample (at App.js:9)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Check this answer out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768685/native-base-datepicker-inside-a-functional-component-throwing-error

Comment: yeah the problem is similar but no fix available there

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you actually tried setting the "value" property on DatePicker  component instead of calling it "date". Maybe it changed names. The previous link has a reference to a fix that has them using that approach, too. (https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3381). For example, just add "value={new Date()}" to your component.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you cancel the picker instead of selecting a new date, it sets the date's value to an undefined value, the solution is the check the event of the onChange function and set it to the previous date state if dismissed eg.

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        setShowDate(false);

        // on cancel set date value to previous date
        if (event?.type === 'dismissed') {
            setDate(date);
            return;
        }
        setDate(selectedDate);
    };
```